# Calculating a hash from a 6-byte field?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm looking for an efficient way to hash a 6-byte field so that it can be used for `std::unordered_map` .

I think this would be the conventional way of creating a hash:

```
struct Hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<uint8_t, 6> & mac) const {
        std::size_t key = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(key, mac[0]);
        boost::hash_combine(key, mac[1]);
        boost::hash_combine(key, mac[2]);
        boost::hash_combine(key, mac[3]);
        boost::hash_combine(key, mac[4]);
        boost::hash_combine(key, mac[5]);
        return key;
    }
};
```

However I noticed that I can make it a little faster (~20%) using this trick:

```
struct Hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<uint8_t, 6> & mac) const {
        std::size_t key = 0;

        // Possibly UB?
        boost::hash_combine(key, reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t&>(mac[0]));
        boost::hash_combine(key, reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t&>(mac[4]));
        return key;
    }
};
```

And this was even faster:

```
struct Hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<uint8_t, 6> & mac) const {
        // Requires size_t to be 64-bit.
        static_assert(sizeof(std::size_t) >= 6, "MAC address doesn't fit in std::size_t!");

        std::size_t key = 0;

        // Likely UB?
        boost::hash_combine(key, 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF & reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t&>(mac[0]));
        return key;
    }
};
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Are these optimizations going to result in UB?
2. Is my first solution the way to go? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What does UB stand for?  "result in UB"?  Perhaps I just need another cup of coffee and am forgetting something obvious.

Comment: @MarkWilkins: Undefined Behavior.

Comment: What about e.g. `boost::hash_combine(key, mac[0] | (mac[1] << 8) | (max[2] << 16) | (max[3] << 24))` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your optimizations are breaking the strict aliasing rules, which leads (standardly speaking) to undefined behavior.

The last optimization worries me the most since you are essentially reading memory you ought not to, which may provoke traps if this memory happened to be protected.

Any reason you are not using [`boost::hash_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/hash_range.html) ?

---

Since `boost::hash_range` turns out not to be as fast as required, I would propose another solution, based on aliasing. Or rather, two solutions in one.

The first idea is that aliasing can be subdued using `char*` as a temporary type.

```
size_t key = 0;
char* k = &reinterpret_cast<char*>(&key);

std::copy(mac.begin(), mac.end(), k);

return key;
```

is therefore a valid implementation of the hash.

However, we can go one step further. Because of alignment and padding, storing a `char[6]` and `char[8]` are likely to use the same amount of memory within a map node. Therefore, we could *enrich* the type, by using `union`:

```
union MacType {
    unsigned char value[8];
    size_t hash;
};
```

Now, you can encapsulate this properly within a class (and make sure you always initialize the bytes `7` and `8` to `0`), and implement the interface of `std::array<unsigned char, 6>` that you actually need.

I've used a similar trick for tiny strings (below 8 characters) for hashing and fast (non-alphabetic) comparisons and it's really sweet.

Comment: +1 for noting the invalid read (+.75 for that and +.25 for clearing up "UB"  ;)

Comment: Just tried `hash_range` and it turns out to be slower than the other solutions. I think this makes sense as the compiler is given less information.

Comment: @MarkWilkins I was aware of the potential invalid read, hence my "Likely UB?" comment. I was thinking that maybe the "0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF" mask would cause the compiler to not read the out-of-bounds part.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: too bad for `hash_range`, I had hoped they had implemented the optimizations for some specializations. In this case, I would recommend a `union`, as I described above.

Comment: My original attempts implemented the key by copying the fields. However, this resulted in a key with bad distribution and would occasionally lead to very bad lookup times. Using boost hash functions fixed this. Your second idea is quite clever and I'll definitely start playing with it.